# Where is save data base made in mysql-workbench?

Tags: mysql, directory, database, mysql-workbench

I want know where are saved by default the data base made with `mysql-workbench`. I want know the directory.

Answer (score 6):

MySQL is a database and you're expected to interact with the database through tools (MySQL Workbench, the `mysql` command line tool, etc.) rather than directly interact with the files on disk.

In order to do a backup, for instance, you would do an SQL dump of your database rather than copying the database files themselves.

To find the files, run the SQL command `show variables where Variable_Name = "datadir"` — but again, you shouldn't interact directly with these files on a regular basis.